# Flutter Firestore fromJson Return Null?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying this but it keeps returning null where am I doing wrong?

```
class UserData {
  final String? name;

  UserData(
      {this.name});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
    };
  }

  UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> doc)
      : this(name: doc['name']! as String);


  factory UserData.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return UserData.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
}
```

and im trying like that

```
factory UserData.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(data['name']); // data is retuning correct
    UserData user = UserData.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    print(user.name); // data is returning null
    return UserData.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
```

Comment: Did you check if `doc.data()` is returning the data from the database?

Comment: I checked, data is returning

Comment: @PeterHaddad i fixed my question about how i tried

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> doc)
  : this(name: doc['name']! as String);
```

to, because `this()` would return a completely new class instance:

```
UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> doc)
  : name = doc['name']! as String;
```

Comment: still returns null